# Geoloqi iphone sample is not working?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios5, geolocation

I downloaded Geoloqi iphone sample,configured my API and secret key after
using my APNS Certificate.but when I set trip message,it is not shown as it is working in their built in application which is in Appstore?Any body has
used their iphone development sample successfully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our [iPhone SDK](https://github.com/geoloqi/iPhone-SDK) project is a good starting point for an app, it is available on Github: [github.com/geoloqi/iPhone-SDK](https://github.com/geoloqi/iPhone-SDK)

It is not clear from your question whether you are talking about the "iPhone SDK" project or the "Geoloqi iPhone" project. You will get much better results from using the iPhone SDK project as a starting point.

If you continue to have trouble you can post error messages or stacktraces here or in our [community forums](https://community.geoloqi.com/).

Comment: hi,  This example is not having any [locationManager startUpdatingLocation]; method.
How  will this development sample application track location?will it be done in Geoloqi server side?
or I have to do implement [locationManager startUpdatingLocation] manually in the code?can you p[lease help?

Comment: The tracking is all handled by the SDK. When you put the SDK into "passive" or "logging" mode, it will make the appropriate [locationManager startUpdatingLocation] calls internally and handle everything for you. You can read more on our [Getting Started Guide](https://developers.geoloqi.com/ios/getting-started)

Comment: @aaronpk, could you also take a look at my this question and try to answer me for feasibility of geoloqi for my requirements?

Comment: @aaronpk - forgot to include the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14958189/ios-api-for-real-time-traffic-data-like-geoloqi-and-waze