# iOS API for real time traffic data (like geoloqi and Waze)

Tags: ios, sdk, gps

I have been visiting some services API web site but can't find what I am looking for. My question is more aimed at what resources to use rather than how exactly it should be done.

My iPhone app requirement is to be able to track users that are nearby, are commuting and locate them on map. Additional requirement maybe texting them, call them, have video session with them etc. On a high level, this will convert to something like:

- get user details based on longitude and latitude
- get to know if they are registered users of the service subscribed
- Sending message to user/users
- Call user using iPhone phone API or dedicated app session
- Video call

[Waze](http://www.waze.com) is one of them. While it is open source, there is quite less documentation on how one can use it as backend for real time traffic data.

Then there is this [Geoloqi](https://developers.geoloqi.com/api) which is paid, but has iOS SDK as well as rich API. However I cannot find sections that are useful to me when I look up to my requirements listed above. What I believe is that there must be many apps already relying on such a useful service. If any of them are open source / tutorials, it would be most useful resource for me for feasibility of geoloqi. Geoloqi also charges users for using their api, so it is also important for me to know what features come at what price .

Comment: you describe many sentences what waze and geoloqui cannot do, but you spent only one vague sentence about what your app should do. please concentrate more on your requirements and describe them.

Comment: Nice reflection. How now?

Comment: spemd 8 sentences of what you want to do, as precisly as possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the level of data/information your interested in, and the functionality, you should just make your own app, I dont think you need those APIs.

You can find and send the coordinates of the people who are using your app to your server.  Then you need to determine the distance between them, to see if they are in the zone of talking, or whatever other functionality you have listed above.

To determine the distance between two people,  This answer should be helpful: [Calculate distance between 2 GPS coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/365826/calculate-distance-between-2-gps-coordinates)

Comment: Nice idea, however I am looking for a readymade server, not a custom made. For now it would suffice if gps related functions are available. Audio,video sessions can be handled using some other api. The app I am developing is for my client who would rather not spend on his own server.